# Poor/slow video on Zoom

Tags: zoom-meeting

I am having a problem with the latest version (5.04) of Zoom on Ubuntu 20.04. The video is slow/delayed. My camera is new and works fine with other video platforms, in addition to the program SayCheese. I need to use Zoom for my business. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same even with the newest 5.4 version. Wondering if it has to do with the nvidia driver or dual monitor setup. Had to abord a meeting because of this.

Comment: I discovered that my laptop had a very high resolution screen ~3K+. I improved zoom performance considerably by dropping the resolution in options to 2540.

Answer (score 1):

I have Zoom 5.1.422789.0705 on Ubuntu 20.04. I have times when Zoom locks up and sends an "unstable internet connection" message on my monitor. The thing is that when I test my internet speed my connection is good. My conclusion is that Zoom will lock up if OTHER connections are bad on a conference call. Meaning that the problem is not necessarily on your computer (other than the incorrect message about unstable connections).

The other thing is that Zoom seems to work better if the window is small (not full screen).